# bash scripting issue while extending sample function

Tags: linux, bash

I am using `abcde` (A better CD encoder) with my raspberry pi and want to use the new functionality of searching for and embedding album art. For this, the `abcde.conf` has a part where you can define your own `post_encode ()` function.

A working example from http://www.andrews-corner.org/getalbumart.html looks like this:

```
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------#
#  A post_encode function to embed album art downloaded with abcde 2.7     #
#  and greater using the new getalbumart function. OUTPUTTYPE must be      # 
#  mp3 and and tagging is with eyeD3. To use this function copy the        # 
#  entire code block and paste it into your ~/.abcde.conf file.            #
#                                                                          # 
#                abcde: Downloading Album Art...                           #
#         http://www.andrews-corner.org/getalbumart.html                   #
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------#
post_encode ()
{
ARTISTFILE="$(mungefilename "$TRACKARTIST")"
ALBUMFILE="$(mungefilename "$DALBUM")"

if [ "$VARIOUSARTISTS" = "y" ] ; then
FINDPATH="$(eval echo "$VAOUTPUTFORMAT")"
else
FINDPATH="$(eval echo "$OUTPUTFORMAT")"
fi

FINALDIR="$(dirname "$OUTPUTDIR/$FINDPATH")"
cd "$FINALDIR"

if [ "$OUTPUTTYPE" = "mp3" ] && [ "$TAGGER" = "$EYED3" ] ; then
vecho "Preparing to embed the album art..." >&2
else
vecho "Not embedding album art, you need mp3 output and eyeD3 tagging..."  >&2
return 1
fi

if [ -e "cover.jpg" ] ; then
for i in *.mp3
do
eyeD3 --add-image cover.jpg:FRONT_COVER "$i"
done

mkdir backup
mv cover.jpg backup
vecho "Your files have had the album art embedded..." >&2
else
vecho "No album art found so no image embedded..." >&2
fi
}
```

I want to be able to do this for several formats in one go (one of the strengths of abcde) and fail getting all in one function.

This is my **failed** attempt at making a `post_encode ()` function:

```
post_encode ()
{
ARTISTFILE="$(mungefilename "$TRACKARTIST")"
ALBUMFILE="$(mungefilename "$DALBUM")"

if [ "$VARIOUSARTISTS" = "y" ] ; then
FINDPATH="$(eval echo "$VAOUTPUTFORMAT")"
else
FINDPATH="$(eval echo "$OUTPUTFORMAT")"
fi

FINALDIR="$(dirname "$OUTPUTDIR/$FINDPATH")"
cd "$FINALDIR"

if [[ "$OUTPUTTYPE" == *"mp3"* ]] && [ "$TAGGER" = "$EYED3" ] ; then
vecho "Preparing to embed the album art..." >&2
else
vecho "Not embedding album art, you need mp3 output and eyeD3 tagging..." >&2
return 1
fi

if [ -e "cover.jpg" ] ; then
for i in *.mp3
do
eyeD3 --add-image cover.jpg:FRONT_COVER "$i"
done

if [[ "$OUTPUTTYPE" == *"flac"* ]] ; then
vecho "Preparing to embed the album art..." >&2
else
vecho "Not embedding album art, you need flac output.." >&2
return 1
fi

if [ -e "cover.jpg" ] ; then
for i in *.flac
do
metaflac --import-picture-from=cover.jpg "$i"
done

mkdir backup
mv cover.jpg backup
vecho "Your files have had the album art embedded..." >&2
else
vecho "No album art found so no image embedded..." >&2
fi
}
```

And here are the complaints of running `abcde`:

```
pi@EMK-RPi2B ~ $ abcde
/etc/abcde.conf: line 512: syntax error at unexpected word `}'
/etc/abcde.conf: line 512: `}'
^[Grabbing entire CD - tracks01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11 12 13 14 15
```

What did I do wrong here? There is only a matching `{}` pair in there, the complaint for line 512 is about the last `}` above ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct this:

```
if [ -e "cover.jpg" ] ; then
for i in *.mp3
do
eyeD3 --add-image cover.jpg:FRONT_COVER "$i"
done
```

On:

```
if [ -e "cover.jpg" ] ; then
for i in *.mp3
do
eyeD3 --add-image cover.jpg:FRONT_COVER "$i"
done
fi
```

Comment: **And that did the trick!** Stupid oversight on my part, I guess. Thanks for the quick help!